# WinBUGS multinomial all parameters are random variables

Tags: multinomial-distribution, bugs

everyone here.
I want to use multinomial distribution, but p[] and N are all random. model is correct and data loaded , model compilied, but it can't still run , it says:value of binomial f[1] must be an integer. Is there anyone here know about it? thank you very much .
this is my coda:

```
model {
   for(s in 1:S) {
   for(i in 1:E) {
         # stochastic part of the likelihood
         Sample[s,i] ~ dpois(lambda[s,i]);
         # link function
         lambda[s,i] <- (w[s]*l[i])*inprod(A[i,1:T],f[1:T]);
         }  
  }
  for(m in 1:T) {
   delta[m] ~ dgamma(alpha[m],1);
    p[m] <- delta[m] / sum(delta[]);
   }
  #  p[1:T] ~ ddirch(alpha[1:T])

  N ~ dpois(lambda1);
  q[1]<- p[1];
  for(k in 2:T){
       q[k] <- p[k]/(1-sum(p[1:(k-1)])); 
  }
 f[1] ~ dbin(q[1],N);
 for(j in 2:(T-1)) {
      tmp[j] <- N-sum(f[1:(j-1)])
      f[j] ~ dbin(q[j],tmp[j])
 }
 f[T]<-N-sum(f[1:(T-1)])

}
```